# Model won't stop stretching when rotated in pose mode-"Now with blend file"

Tags: animation, rigging, pose-mode

For some reason my weapon won't stop stretching when it is rotated in pose mode. I have added a blend file link for further investigation.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/16FL62jCmqhW1C0qgNXEGm_Fpp5D9ssgI/view?usp=sharing

[image: GunStretch?]

Comment: hello, its vertices are probably part of several vertex groups, you could remove them from all groups them reassign to the good bone again

Comment: you should provide your blend file so we can check it out

Answer (score 1):

You have forgotten to apply the *Scale* to the armature of the gun. It's highly recommended to apply all transformations to the armature before you use it. Select the gun object and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> in *Object* mode. The *All Transformations* option includes *Location*, *Scale* and *Rotation*.

All steps for the fix:

- first, make sure *Auto Keying* is turned off so that you don't mess up your animation.
- apply the *Scale* to the *Armature* object. The gun bones will move up 50m into the sky.
- to fix their location move the 3D cursor to the gun mesh object (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> *Cursor to Selection*), then you can easily move the gun bones back to the gun with *Selection to Cursor*
- fix the location of the hands (*Child Of* constraints -> *Clear Inverse*)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: can you elaborate a little further in how you apply the scale to all transforms?

Comment: I've edited the question to make it more clear. *All Transformations* is an option and it includes the scale. The rotation and location are ok, but you forgot the scale. Applying the scale resets it to 1.000 as shown in the screenshot and keeps its current size. The scale of your gun's armature is something like 0.0xx and this causes the bad deformation.